# How to skip null images in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, time-series

I've called sentinel2 image collection but I don't know how can I skip null images instead of filter.neq():

code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b762152c33e6eddca96c2006e62eed54

```
var s22 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
.filterDate(start_date,end_date)
.filterBounds(table)
.filter(ee.Filter.lessThan('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',45))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('PRODUCT_ID','S2A_MSIL1C_20180518T071621_N0206_R006_T39SUR_20180518T093201'));
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "null images", as that is not a concept in Earth Engine. Do you mean images that do not intersect your area of interest?

Comment: when I call sentinel2 images in google earth engine, some images doesn't have values and code returns erros like this:

(ImageCollection (Error)
Error in map(ID=20170910T071621_20170910T073037_T39SUR): Image.constant: Parameter 'value' is required)

when I've checked the mentioned image, I saw that it doesn't have values for processing. Now I'm gonna to know that how can I ignore these kinds of data in image collection automatically.

Comment: Why does the error say `Image.constant`? It seems like you are trying to do some further analysis. To be able to help you should share the code that returns that error